# Trouble with $trim inside jquery document.ready

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a div and display a div if another div is empty. The following code works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmpty( el ){
  return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
if (isEmpty($('#region-content-copy'))) {
$('.regionseo').hide();   
$('#generalbanners').show();   
 }   
</script>
```

But when I try to put it inside a document.ready, it fails. Can anybody shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function isEmpty( el ){
  return !$.trim(el.html())
 }
if (isEmpty($('#region-content-copy'))) {
$('.regionseo').hide();   
$('#generalbanners').show();   
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you declare a function inside document ready? Put the function definition outside and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to know if your div is empty, you should count the number of children of your div.

I would replace your function isEmpty by :

```
function isEmpty( el ){
  if(el.children().length==0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

And as seb said it, you have to define your function out of the document ready block, and only let the call of this function in your ducment ready block.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put it in document.ready, you should do like this,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        function isEmpty(el) {
            return !$.trim(el.html())
        }
        if (isEmpty($('#region-content-copy'))) {
            $('.regionseo').hide();
            $('#generalbanners').show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var chk = inEmpty($('#region-content-copy'));
  // check the chk for your requirement
}
 function inEmpty(el){
   return !el.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
 }
```